# Python: Shrink/Extend 2D arrays in fractions

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, shrink

There are `2D arrays` of numbers as outputs of some numerical processes in the form of `1x1, 3x3, 5x5, ...` shaped, that correspond to different resolutions.

In a stage an average i.e., 2D array value in the shape `nxn` needs to be produced.
If the outputs were in consistency of shape i.e., say all in `11x11` the solution was obvious, so:

`element_wise_mean_of_all_arrays`.

For the problem of this post however the arrays are in different shapes so the obvious way does not work!

I thought it might be some help by using [`kron` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.kron.html) however it didn't. For example, if array is in shape of `17x17` how to make it `21x21`. So for all others from `1x1`,`3x3`,..., to build a constant-shaped array, say `21x21`.
Also it can be the case that the arrays are smaller and bigger in shape compared to the target shape. That is an array of `31x31` to be shruk into `21x21`.

You could imagine the problem as a very common task for images, being shrunk or extended.

**What are possible efficient approaches to do the same jobs on `2D` arrays, in Python, using numpy, scipy, etc?**

**Updates:**
Here is a bit optimized version of the accepted answer bellow:

```
def resize(X,shape=None):
    if shape==None:
        return X
    m,n = shape
    Y = np.zeros((m,n),dtype=type(X[0,0]))
    k = len(X)
    p,q = k/m,k/n
    for i in xrange(m):
        Y[i,:] = X[i*p,np.int_(np.arange(n)*q)]
    return Y
```

It works perfectly, however do you all agree it is **the best choice** in terms of the efficiency? If not any improvement?

```
# Expanding ---------------------------------

>>> X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]

>>> resize(X,[7,11])
[[1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6]
 [4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6]
 [7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 9 9 9]
 [7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 9 9 9]]

# Shrinking ---------------------------------

>>> X = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16]]

>>> resize(X,(2,2))
[[ 1  3]
 [ 9 11]]
```

**Final note:** that the code above easily could be translated to `Fortran` for the highest performance possible.

Comment: the resize() return [[1,1,1,..,1],[1,1,1,..,1],..,[1,1,1,..,1]]. It didn't work as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying but if what I think the simplest way would be:

```
wanted_size = 21
a = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = numpy.zeros((wanted_size, wanted_size))

for i in range(wanted_size):
    for j in range(wanted_size):
        idx1 = i * len(a) / wanted_size
        idx2 = j * len(a) / wanted_size
        b[i][j] = a[idx1][idx2]
```

You could maybe replace the b[i][j] = a[idx1][idx2] with some custom function like the average of a 3x3 matrix centered in a[idx1][idx2] or some interpolation function.

Comment: Thanks; your answer works well. I did some optimizations and put the new one (defined as a function) in the question. After a while if there was not a better solution in terms of the efficiency, this could be of course my choice.

Comment: I'm also curious of a more efficient way but I don't see a way you can build a n*m matrix where each element needs to be computed without doing at least n*m computations.

Comment: With `Fortran` version of the code (above in the question) that I developed based on your answer, the performance is outstanding. Thus I accepted your answer for its simplicity in implementation.